# how to assign names, read from a txt file1, to columns of data file2 in R

Tags: r

I have file1.txt with 2 columns, 1st of serial number from 1 to 100 and 2nd of strings. Another file, file2.txt with 100 columns of data. File2.txt doesn't contain any column name. I want to assign strings, read from file1.txt, to columns of file2.txt. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read the list of strings with `readLines()` and then assign them to the `data.frame` with `names<-`

```
dd <- read.table("file2.txt", header=F)
dn <- read.table("file1.txt", header=T)
names(dd)<- as.character(dn[,2])
```

Comment: Thanks! But I just realized that file1.txt contains 2 columns, first is serial number and other the string which I would use as column name. How to proceed now?

Comment: @bipvan You should updated your original question based on this information. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: -- The code is working for a very small file but for my data, the result on console is displaying column names as either "integers" or NA

Comment: @bipvan I guess you can try adding the `as.character` as i've done in the edit. Are you sure `nrow(dd)==`nrow(dn)`? Without data to test it's hard to debug.